# Check for the occurrence of the given items in a collection

Tags: c#, .net

i want to check for the occurrence of some given items in the collection and thought it work like this but it doesn't

```
public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> otherCollection)
{
        if (otherCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherCollection", ExceptionResources.NullParameterUsed);
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection", ExceptionResources.ExtensionUsedOnNull);
        else
            return Enumerable.Any<T>(otherCollection, new Func<T, bool>(((Enumerable)collection).Contains<T>));
}
```

I want to get true if the specified collection contains any of the otherCollection items, otherwise false.
But there is an error telling me that i can not convert system.collections.generic.iEnumerable>T> in system.linq.Enumberable. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You should think about the desired answer when either collection is empty (not null). Not as trivial as it looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
return otherCollection.Any(collection.Contains);
```

You don't need any cast to call `Contains` method,because there is already an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as first parameter.